# Bootstrap how to positioning ?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I position col-md-4 - inside bottom of col-md-12 ?

( post img )
[image](http://myhotel.ovh/bootstrap.jpg)

-----------col-md-12----------------

(empty space)

---col-md-4--- / ---col-md-4--- / ---col-md-4---

----------end col-md-12---------------------

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 hero">
        <img src="http:/placehold.it/1600x800" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: change the padding of the .col-md-4 divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 hero">
        <img src="http:/placehold.it/1600x800" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="row" id="pseudo-box">
             <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Apply the `#pseudo-box` and position it in the parent div according to your convenience.

Comment: do I need to set absulute and relative position ?

Comment: You should use `position` as `absolute` because if you use `relative` then the space above would not be much usable.

Comment: ... can you write css ? - i still have problem
http://www.bootply.com/DgtfI0vJqO#

Comment: `#pseudo-box{ position : absolute ; top : 200px;}`